# Pandas not corectly merged with wrong location and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have some stock market data and I want to merge 2 CSV file that contain OHLCV value and another one is my own calculated value named "hd" added after column "Volume" with condition:

1. Matching the Ticker Name
2. Matching the Date

I just try this merging code with `left` method, but the output is wrong position of value and some column not merged, how to merge it correctly?

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = pd.read_csv('ohlcv286.csv', parse_dates=True)
data2 = pd.read_csv('hd286.csv', parse_dates=True)

data2['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data2['Date/Time']).dt.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

print(data2.tail(5))
print(data1.tail(5))

merge = data1.merge(data2, on=['Ticker','Date/Time'], how='left').fillna(0)

print(merge.tail(5))
print(merge.info())

merge.to_csv('exp.csv', index=False)
```

screenshot:
[image: dataframe]

output:

```
  Ticker   Date/Time            hd
0   ABDA  06/04/2021 -4.000000e+11
1   ABDA  06/11/2021 -4.000000e+11
2   ABDA  14/06/2021 -4.000000e+11
3   ABDA  15/06/2021 -4.000000e+11
4   ABDA  17/06/2021 -4.000000e+11
  Ticker   Date/Time    Open    High     Low   Close     Volume
0   AALI  02/06/2021  8900.0  9100.0  8825.0  9075.0  2188500.0
1   AALI  03/06/2021  9125.0  9325.0  9100.0  9200.0  2495200.0
2   AALI  04/06/2021  9225.0  9250.0  9150.0  9175.0  1298300.0
3   AALI  07/06/2021  9175.0  9325.0  9100.0  9125.0  1377700.0
4   AALI  08/06/2021  9125.0  9175.0  8800.0  8875.0  2981000.0
  Ticker   Date/Time    Open    High     Low   Close     Volume         hd
0   AALI  02/06/2021  8900.0  9100.0  8825.0  9075.0  2188500.0        0.0
1   AALI  03/06/2021  9125.0  9325.0  9100.0  9200.0  2495200.0        0.0
2   AALI  04/06/2021  9225.0  9250.0  9150.0  9175.0  1298300.0        0.0
3   AALI  07/06/2021  9175.0  9325.0  9100.0  9125.0  1377700.0 -9896930.0
4   AALI  08/06/2021  9125.0  9175.0  8800.0  8875.0  2981000.0 -8427643.0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 103256 entries, 0 to 103255
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count   Dtype  
---  ------     --------------   -----  
 0   Ticker     103256 non-null  object 
 1   Date/Time  103256 non-null  object 
 2   Open       103256 non-null  float64
 3   High       103256 non-null  float64
 4   Low        103256 non-null  float64
 5   Close      103256 non-null  float64
 6   Volume     103256 non-null  float64
 7   hd         103256 non-null  float64
dtypes: float64(6), object(2)
memory usage: 7.1+ MB
None

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Solution from @not_speshal
some date reversed and make the data messy when it visualize
[image: messy date order]
[image: Some date reversed order]

[OHLCV data](https://vortex369.dev/s/rTBEKxQXcc9XG9B)

[Self Calculated Value](https://vortex369.dev/s/y7Yqn6cX2PAHw2m)

[Output](https://vortex369.dev/s/x3jtXFCZ9bzCMsz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like some of the values in the "Date/Time" column have both date and time and some have only the date. Try keeping only the dates before merging:

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('ohlcv286.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('hd286.csv')

data1["Date/Time"] = pd.to_datetime(data1["Date/Time"], format="%d/%m/%Y")
data2["Date/Time"] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(data2["Date/Time"], format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").dt.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

output = data1.merge(data2, on=['Ticker','Date/Time'], how='left').fillna(0)

>>> output
       Ticker  Date/Time    Open  ...   Close     Volume            hd
0        AALI 2021-06-02  8900.0  ...  9075.0  2188500.0 -5.738800e+06
1        AALI 2021-06-03  9125.0  ...  9200.0  2495200.0 -5.717932e+06
2        AALI 2021-06-04  9225.0  ...  9175.0  1298300.0 -5.799378e+06
3        AALI 2021-06-07  9175.0  ...  9125.0  1377700.0 -5.916303e+06
4        AALI 2021-06-08  9125.0  ...  8875.0  2981000.0 -6.594500e+06
      ...        ...     ...  ...     ...        ...           ...
103251   ZYRX 2021-11-19   580.0  ...   565.0  7308900.0 -1.996443e+10
103252   ZYRX 2021-11-22   565.0  ...   575.0  7221700.0 -1.996425e+10
103253   ZYRX 2021-11-23   575.0  ...   570.0  7555100.0 -1.996424e+10
103254   ZYRX 2021-11-24   570.0  ...   575.0  7803100.0 -1.996366e+10
103255   ZYRX 2021-11-25   575.0  ...   560.0  5545200.0 -1.996360e+10

[103256 rows x 8 columns]
```

###### Output (Ticker: INKP):

[image]

Comment: I try your solution but something strange happened, the converted date mixing one each other and make the visualization messy because some other date is reversed order about the day and month section..

@not_speshal

Comment: I can't help you without the required data - provide samples using `data1.head().to_dict()` and `data2.head().to_dict()`. Be sure to include some rows that are causing your issue.

Comment: I have edited the question with your solution screenshoot and link of sample data.. thanks before.

Comment: @testhink - I updated the code to use your actual data and can't find what errors you're talking about. I have no idea what the graph means in your question. Also don't know what you mean by "some date reversed and make the data messy"